# How can I write this function, passed as an argument, that returns a pointer?

Tags: pointers, char, function-pointers, smart-pointers

I am writing a piece of code and I would like to know whats the best way to write it.

```
std::string text;

text = std::string("Greetings");
arduino.writeSerialPort(convToChar(text));
```

The function convToChar() returns char*.

I wanted to have the least lines possible and not to do this :

```
std::string text;

text = std::string("Greetings");
char* writable = convToChar(text);
arduino.writeSerialPort(writable);
delete[] writable;
```

But the problem in the first piece of code is I don't delete the char* returned by the function convToChar() (am I right ?). Then I read about smart pointers. Should I use them ? If yes, can someone give me the good syntax because I don't find any info about my specific case (with a function passed as an argument).

Sincerely yours

Comment: What does `convToChar` actually do? Anything more than `text.c_str()`? Do you actually need the `std::string` or can't you just write `arduino.writeSerialPort("Greetings");`? How does `writeSerialPort` know how many chars it has to write?

Comment: `convTochar()` does the same than `c_str()` but with the difference that it ends the array with '\n' instead of '\0' and it returns a `char*`, not a `const char*`. I have to pass a `char*` as an argument and not `const char*` so I cannot directly write "Greetings" as an argument. `writeSerialPort()` does know how many chars from a second argument but I took it off because my main question is more about memory allocations.